# Two git remotes with different history

Tags: git, github

We have an internal corporate github repository that we want to open-source to [github.com](https://www.github.com) soon. In order to do so safely we want to remove the git history upon the initial push to the public repo. Therefore we need to:

1. Create a public repo that we add as 2nd remote to our local github repo
2. Push a history-truncated version of our local code to the public repo
3. Ensure that all follow-up commits end up in both the local repo and the public repo

As an example, if the local history at the time of the initial public push is:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

then the public repo after the initial push should look like:

```
D
```

After adding two new commits, E and F, the two repos should looks like this respectively:

Local:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

Public:

```
D -> E -> F
```

**How can we achieve all of that simultaneously as easily as possible?** I realize that there are lots of questions/answers regarding truncating history or having more than one remote, but I haven't found anything about both of those features simultaneously.

Comment: If the plan is to keep all future revisions of the internal and the external repo in sync, then save yourself a butt-ton of trouble and just turn the history-sanitized version into "the one truth" and also use that internally. Keep the old one around for archive purposes, but continue working on the new one. Everything else will be ugly as hell as git will never treat the "same" commit on those two repos as in any way, shape or form related. *If* you have to go through with it, you'll want some sort of auto-merging happening into the public repo.

Comment: @JoachimSauer merging is not a good idea, as that would bring the private history back into the public history. You would need to cherry pick E and F onto the public D, whicch I'd call D'. You'd end up with D' -> E' -> F'. I fully agree with Joachim, though, this will not be easy, you'll always have divergent history.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a initial commit for your public repo, and use `git replace --graft` to sort of bind your internal and public histories together. I have personally found this solution to be great in a similar situation as you described in your question. In this case the histories will look like this:

History in your internal Github repo:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> I (replaced) -> E -> F
```

History in your public Github repo:

```
I -> E -> F
```

where commits `E` and `F` are new development and `I` is the initial commit for public repo.

Steps to achieve this (assuming master is the main branch in all repos):

- At your stating point you are in commit `D`
- Copy the files to a new folder and create the initial commit `I` for you public repo
- Push the initial commit to your (empty) public repo
- Go back to your old local repo and add the new public remote
- Pull the initial commit from public repo to a new branch
- Check the hashes of commits `D` and `I`
- On the new branch, run `git replace --graft hash_of_commit_I hash_of_commit_D`
- When you run `git show-ref` you'll see ref `refs/replace/*`
- `git log` will show `replaced` mark on commit `I`
- Merge new branch to master (`I` to master)
- Push new reference to your internal repo `git push internal_remote 'refs/replace/*'`
- Push initial commit to your internal repo `git push internal_remote HEAD:master`
- At this point you can delete the new branch
- Pushing to public repo should not do anything `git push public_remote master`, there should only be the initial commit `I` and no previous history
- Now you can make new development and push to both remotes without messing up the history!
- `git commit`
- `git push internal_remote master`
- `git push public_remote master`

Comment: This worked like a charm to push a small, local repo (no internal remote) to GitHub without its commit history, despite many comments here and elsewhere saying that this would be a nightmare.
Having no internal remote, I simply skipped the `git push internal_remote` steps while following the procedure.

Comment: I've tried to convert this English description to code (as English it's ambiguous) and it does not work for me. Code at https://pastebin.com/dYZibMDs Is there something I did wrong in my interpretation? The 'test_public' gets the full history on the last push :(.